# How to increase height of font in pdf

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using the Leaves Example downloaded from github for ebook reader purpose.Is there any solution in that leaves example to increase /decrease height of font of the pdf.

Is that possible in leaves example or with some other example .Basically what i want is page curl effect same as leaves project and also increase / decrease font height .

If some one can provide code or any idea it would be great help .

Thansks in advance

Comment: did u get the answer for this.If yes please help!